# Using recursion to pass parameters with base cases

Tags: java, recursion, radix

I am trying to complete the printConvertedNumber method to use recursion to print the first parameter in the number base specified by the second parameter. Converting to base 2,4 and 8 all use the same algorithm. The % and / operators with the desired base as the right operand are used to convert the number to the desired base. I am trying not to declare any new variables or objects in the class.

here is what it should look like, [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXPWR.png)

Here is what I have so far, note my attempt does not work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class NumberBaseConversion
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number,
        base;

    do
    {
      System.out.print("Enter a positive base 10 number: ");
      number = input.nextInt();
    } while (number <= 0);
    do
    {
      System.out.print("Enter a base (2, 4, or 8): ");
      base = input.nextInt();
    } while (base != 2 && base != 4 && base != 8);
    printConvertedNumber(number, base);
    System.out.println();
  }

  private static void printConvertedNumber(int num, int base)
  {
    if (base <= 0) 
    { 
      return; 
    }
    System.out.println("num: " + num + ", base: " + base);
    printConvertedNumber(num/base,num%base);
  }
}
```

here is what i get when i run it

[what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWDLv.png)

Comment: You're getting a `ArithmeticException: / by zero` we know dividing by 0 doesn't work in real life. It also won't work in programming.

Comment: Put this `System.out.println("num: " + num + ", base: " + base);` at the beginning of your `printConvertedNumber()` method. It'll help you out.

Comment: I'm telling you to print it for debugging purposes. Or use a debugger. In any case, you need to check if `base` <=0, if it is then you want to return. So add the following at the beginning of your method:`if (base <= 0) { return; }` so that you dont get that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `printConvertedNumber` method. You're not checking once `num` drops below 0. Also, the recursive call to the method is a little off. Try this:

```
private static void printConvertedNumber(int num, int base) {
    if (num <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    printConvertedNumber(num / base, base);
    System.out.print(num % base);
}
```

Here are a few sample runs:

> run:
>   Enter a positive base 10 number: 10
>   Enter a base (2, 4, or 8): 2
>   1010
>
> run:
>   Enter a positive base 10 number: 4
>   Enter a base (2, 4, or 8): 2
>   100
>
> run:
>   Enter a positive base 10 number: 10
>   Enter a base (2, 4, or 8): 8
>   12
>
> run:
>   Enter a positive base 10 number: 10
>   Enter a base (2, 4, or 8): 4
>   22
>
> run:
>   Enter a positive base 10 number: 23
>   Enter a base (2, 4, or 8): 4
>   113

You can check your answers against [this website](http://www.kaagaard.dk/service/convert.htm).
Also, kudos on JGrasp. That was my first IDE.